# Lua script with C++ : attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value)

Tags: c++, io, lua

I'm going to write a program using lua fo AI, so I'm trying to make it works together.
But when I try to load a lua script from my cpp file I've got this error message :

```
-- toto.lua:1: attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value)
```

Here is my lua script :

`io.write("Running ", _VERSION, "\n")`

And here is my cpp file :

```
void report_errors(lua_State *L, int status)
{
  if ( status!=0 ) {
  std::cerr << "-- " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
  lua_pop(L, 1); // remove error message                                                            
  }
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  for ( int n=1; n<argc; ++n ) {
  const char* file = argv[n];

  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();

  luaopen_io(L); // provides io.*                                                                   
  luaopen_base(L);
  luaopen_table(L);
  luaopen_string(L);
  luaopen_math(L);

  std::cerr << "-- Loading file: " << file << std::endl;

  int s = luaL_loadfile(L, file);

  if ( s==0 ) {
    s = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
  }

  report_errors(L, s);
  lua_close(L);
  std::cerr << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code creates a separate Lua state for each file that it runs. This will prevent different files from communicating. This may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call the luaopen_* functions directly. Use either [luaL_openlibs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_openlibs) or [luaL_requiref](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_requiref) instead:

```
luaL_requiref(L, "io", luaopen_io, 1);
```

The particular problem here is that `luaopen_io` does not store the module table in `_G`, hence the complaint that `io` is a `nil` value. Take a look at the source code for luaL_requiref in lauxlib.c if you want to know the gory details.

Comment: Thanks, it works properly now, I use luaL_openlibs instead. I'll keep in mind your advise !

Comment: It helps. Could you please elaborate on why luaopen_* does not work? It is the first thing you see in their documentation

Comment: @VladLazarenko The luaopen_* functions simply create a table (mostly containing functions) on top of the stack. What is missing is associating that table with a name so that it can be accessed from within Lua and registering it with the module loading mechanism. Those two steps however are _the same for all libraries_. Think of the luaopen_* function as what the library writer provides for setting up that particular library. Its goal is not to do the complete library loading but rather provide the information that luaL_requiref needs to perform the loading instead.